# problems with Array.prototype.slice.appy(arguments, 1)

Tags: javascript, node.js

1) I have the following code:

> ```
> var callIt = function(fn) {
>     return fn.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, 1));
> };
> ```

when callIt is called in nodejs, it complains:

```
    return fn.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, 1));
                                                ^
TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type
```

2) If I change the callIt to:

> ```
> var callIt = function(fn) {
>     return fn.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
> };
> ```

Nodejs does not complain, but the result is not what expected, with the extra first argument passed in.

3) If I change the callIt to:

> ```
> var callIt = function(fn) {
>     var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
>     return Function.prototype.apply(fn, args.slice(1));
>     //return fn.apply(this, args.slice(1)); //same as above
>
> };
> ```

It works as expected.

4) If I run test in Chrome developer Tools Console like this:

> ```
> > var o={0:"a", 1:"asdf"}
> undefined
> > o
> Object
> 0: "a"
> 1: "asdf"
> __proto__: Object
> > Array.prototype.slice.call(o,1)
> []
> > Array.prototype.slice.call(o)
> []
> ```

Now slice does not work on array-like object.

I am baffled on these. Please explain.

I referenced the following:
[Array_generic_methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the [`apply` method of functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) expects an array as its second parameter - that's where your TypeError comes from, you passed `1`. Instead, use `[1]` or better the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
fn.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
```

The reason why it didn't work on `{0:"a", 1:"asdf"}` is that this is *not* an array-like object - it has no `length` property. `[].slice.call({0:"a", 1:"asdf", length:2}, 0)` would do it.

Comment: Thank all of you. I am newbie to javascript and just trying to test the serious part on javascript recently.